# Filtering each criteria in Autofilter and copy data to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if there is a way to filter all the criteria using  `Autofilter` in one go (let say we have three criteria) and copy the data to another worksheet, using VBA.

I'm adding an image for reference.

[[image: Reference Image 1]]

Comment: you can do this one without vba using show Report Filter Pages option in Pivot Table

Comment: @HarshaVardhan is right. But if you want the VBA code instead you just have to do it once manually and record your doings with the macro recorder: Excel will write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pivot Table :

1. Create a Pivot Table
2. Drag designation to the filter
3. Employee code to Row Labels
4. Distance to the values

Finally go to the options tab,

[image: Options]

If you want to automate, record these steps.

Answer (score 0):

It is always expected that you try and post the code you tried. Please post your efforts as its encourages people to come out and help you.

I have tried a piece of code to give you an Idea about, Kindly have a look at them and let me know if that works.

```
Sub autofilter_copy()

    'Declare the Required Variables
    Dim Colm As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

ws.Activate

'Get Column Number of Designation Column
Colm = WorksheetFunction.Match("Designation", Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1), 0)

'Get Last row of the Designation Column
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, Colm).End(xlUp).Row

 ' Usage of Advanced Filter to get the Unique Values
ActiveSheet.Range("C1:C13").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1"), Unique:=True

Range("D1").Value = "Designation Unique"

Colm2 = WorksheetFunction.Match("Designation Unique", Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1), 0)

lastrow2 = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, Colm2).End(xlUp).Row

'For loop to loop through the Unique values and paste the values in a new sheet.
For i = 2 To lastrow2

ws.Activate

UniqueValue = Range("D" & i).Value
Cells.Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C" & lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=UniqueValue
Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Paste

ws.Activate
Next
End Sub
```